# Generate random UUID

Tags: code-golf, random

## I need a UUID. Your job is to generate one.

The canonical UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier) is a 32 digit hexadecimal number with hyphens inserted in certain points.The program should output 32 hex digits (128 bits), in the form of `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` (`8-4-4-4-12` digits), where `x` is a random hexadecimal number. Assuming that your language's PRNG is perfect, all valid outputs must have the same probability of being generated.

### TL;DR

Generate 32 random hexadecimal digits in the  form `8-4-4-4-12` digits. Shortest code wins.

EDIT: Must be hexadecimal. Always generating decimal only is invalid.
EDIT 2: No built-ins. These aren't GUIDs, just generic hex digits.

---

### Example output:

```
ab13901d-5e93-1c7d-49c7-f1d67ef09198
7f7314ca-3504-3860-236b-cface7891277
dbf88932-70c7-9ae7-b9a4-f3df1740fc9c
c3f5e449-6d8c-afe3-acc9-47ef50e7e7ae
e9a77b51-6e20-79bd-3ee9-1566a95d9ef7
7b10e43c-3c57-48ed-a72a-f2b838d8374b
```

Input, and [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.
Also, feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: To be clear, we should print *one* randomly generated UUID, yes?

Comment: Seems like a less strict version of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32309/14215

Comment: @Dennis: correct.

Comment: @Geobits: true, but not a duplicate :P

Comment: _"These examples are not random. Try to attach some significance."_ What does that mean?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Sure, the intended output is strikingly similar, but all answers from [Generate four type-4 GUIDs for me](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32309) only use 448 bits of entropy.

Comment: @AlexA. I took the idea from [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54734/barcodegolf-generate-a-numbers-upc/)

Comment: Actually, one does not need hexadecimal numbers, 10-base can also be random. For example, `12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012` should be a valid UUID (or is any hex digit necessary?). Do you consider this a loophole?

Comment: The title and first sentence suggest that you want a canonical UUID, and the examples given appear to follow the spec for UUIDs, but you actually seem to be asking for something else.

Comment: The required format user version 1 to version 5 and invalid formats for a UUID. Please, read about version 4 and decide what you want.

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that the version 4 (random) UUID has a required format of `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`  where `y` is one of `[89AB]`.  At the time of this comment, none of the answers (except C# using a built in library) are guaranteed to produce a valid random UUID (and actually, are quite likely to not produce one).

Comment: This challenge isn't specifically for any version of UUIDs, but just generating a generic `8-4-4-4-12` string. The output strings look to be UUIDv4 but there's already a UUIDv4 challenge.

Comment: @Voitcus It could be a loophole, but I specified in the question that it should be in hexadecimal.

Comment: @ConfusedMr_C I can add a letter `A` at the end of the output string and there will be hexadecimal digit. In my opinion your question is not clear.

Comment: I'd suggest the following wording: *Assuming that your language's PRNG is perfect, all valid outputs must have the same probability of being generated.*

Comment: Ooh, thanks! :D I'll use that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Pyth, 20 bytes

```
j\-msm.HO16*4hdj83 3
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%5C-msm.HO16%2a4hdj83+3&debug=0)

Encodes `[1, 0, 0, 0, 2]` as 83 in base 3, then adds one and multiplies by four to get the length of each segment. Then makes hex digits and joins on hyphens.

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
8 4__C]{{Gmr"%x"e%}*'-}/;
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=8%204__C%5D%7B%7BGmr%22%25x%22e%25%7D*'-%7D%2F%3B).

#### How it works

```
8 4__C]{              }/   For each I in [8 4 4 4 12]:
        {         }*         Do I times:
         Gmr                   Pseudo-randomly select an integer between 0 and 15.
            "%x"e%             Apply hexadecimal string formatting.
                    '-       Push a hyphen-minus.
                        ;  Discard the last hyphen-minus.
```

Answer (score 8):

## Julia, 80 bytes

```julia
h=hex(rand(Uint128),32)
print(h[1:8]"-"h[9:12]"-"h[13:16]"-"h[17:20]"-"h[21:32])
```

Generate a random 128-bit integer, get its hexidecimal representation as a string padded to 32 digits, and divide that into segments joined with dashes.

Thanks to ConfusedMr_C and kvill for their help!

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 43 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@Xcali](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72767/xcali)!

```perl
printf"%04x"."-"x/[2-5]/,rand 2**16for 1..8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1J1cCkQklPSVepQj/aSNc0Vl@nKDEvRcFIS8vQLC2/SMFQT8/i/38A)

Comment: Shaved two bytes, still using your basic method: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1J1cCkQklPSVepQj/aSNc0Vl@nKDEvRcFIS8vQLC2/SMFQT8/i/38A "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## PowerShell, <strike>77</strike> <strike>69</strike> 67 bytes

```
((8,4,4,4,12)|%{((1..$_)|%{'{0:X}'-f(random(16))})-Join""})-Join"-"
```

edit: extraneous parens:

```
((8,4,4,4,12)|%{((1..$_)|%{('{0:X}'-f(random(16)))})-Join""})-Join"-"
```

edit: was able to remove the trailing .Trim("-") from the original:

```
(((8,4,4,4,12)|%{((1..$_)|%{('{0:X}'-f(random(16)))})+"-"})-Join"").Trim("-")
```

It may be clearer with some whitespace given the nature of the flags (-f and -Join). I would still like to lose the final Trim("-"):

```
(((8,4,4,4,12)|%{((1..$_)|%{('{0:X}' -f (random(16)))}) + "-"}) -Join "").Trim("-")
```

Or, using the built-in functionality (ala the C# answer above)

```
'{0}'-f[System.Guid]::NewGuid()
```

However, it seems a wee bit shortcut-y even if it comes in at 31 bytes.

Comment: 61 byte: `(8,4,4,4,12|%{-join(1..$_|%{'{0:X}'-f(random(16))})})-join'-'`

Comment: `(New-Guid).ToString()`

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>86</s> 84 bytes

```
from random import*;print'-'.join('%%0%ix'%i%randint(0,16**i-1)for i in[8,4,4,4,12])
```

This chains string formatters to make Python format the hex numbers uniquely for each segment.

Ungolfed:

```
import random

final = []
for i in [8, 4, 4, 4, 12]:               # Iterate through every segment
    max = (16 ** i) - 1                  # This is the largest number that can be
                                         # represented in i hex digits
    number = random.randint(0, max)      # Choose our random segment
    format_string = '%0' + str(i) + 'x'  # Build a format string to pad it with zeroes
    final.append(format_string % number) # Add it to the list

print '-'.join(final)                    # Join every segment with a hyphen and print
```

This could use some improvement, but I'm proud.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 69 <s>72</s> <s>75</s> bytes

```
foreach([8,4,4,4,12]as$c)$r[]=rand(".1e$c","1e$c");echo join('-',$r);
```

This does not output hex digits (`a`, ... `f`). They are allowed, but not required by the question body.

No digit group starts with `0` (also not required).

*edit: saved 3 bytes thanks to @IsmaelMiguel*

Comment: That looks like a bi more than 32 bytes.

Comment: @isaacg yes, sorry - my mistake

Comment: You should use [`join()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) instead.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, ES6, 106 bytes

```
"8-4-4-4-12".replace(/\d+/g, m => {t=0;for(i=0; i<m; i++) {t+=(Math.random()*16|0).toString(16)}return t})
```

Uses Regex replace. Treats the format string as a count for generating a hex char. Hoisting wherever I can; omitting semicolons where possible.

Comment: 89 bytes, `'8-4-4-4-12'.replace(/\d+/g,n=>Math.floor(16**n*Math.random()).toString(16).padStart(n,0))`

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 65 Bytes

```
using System;class C{void Main(){Console.Write(Guid.NewGuid());}}
```

edit: Yes ! C# is shorter than another Language (besides Java) :)

Comment: I think this is considered a standard loophole... :( http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default

Comment: I think this is not considered a standard loophole: As you can see the request to abandon this stuff just got 2 upvotes in over 1 year. Contrarily the comment that says you should use built-in-functions got 58 upvotes. Or as one commenter said --> If we were all limited to the same set of built-in functions, every contest would be won by APL or Golfscript because their command names are the shortest. (Michael Stern)

Comment: or to just put it another way around: Can we use printf? or should we use inline asm to trigger interupt 21?

Comment: A good point! I didn't intend to upset, I only meant to be helpful! I guess then, Mathematica could win with `CreateUUID[]`!

Comment: @StephanSchinkel The "only 2 upvotes in a year" is misleading. It has 47 upvotes and 45 downvotes right now, so a net +2. That being said, the generally accepted threshold is higher than that, so you're right that it doesn't "really" count as a standard loophole right now.

Comment: *However*, does that function give a formatted GUID with certain positions fixed? If so, I don't think it qualifies, since the spec says every `x` position (32 total) should be random.

Comment: Is this valid? The OP edited in *"No built-ins. These aren't GUIDs, just generic hex digits."*

Comment: Don't know who is downvoting me here. Please have a look at when I answered the question. I answered at Revision 3 of the question. Current Revision is 7. No built ins came with Revision 6. 4 days after I have answered the question. But thanks nonetheless :-)

Answer (score 3):

## gawk, 86

```
BEGIN{for(srand();j++<32;printf(j~"^9|13|17|21"?"-":E)"%c",x+(x>10?87:48))x=rand()*16}
```

You can use this once every second to generate a unique random "UUID". This is because `srand()` uses the system time in seconds since epoch as argument if there is no argument given.

```
for n in `seq 100` do awk 'BEGIN{for(srand();j++<32;printf(j~"^9|13|17|21"?"-":E)"%c",x+(x>10?87:48))x=rand()*16}'; sleep 1; done
```

I think the awk part is rather elegant.

```
BEGIN{
    srand()
    for(;j++<32;) {
        x=rand()*16
        x+=(x>10?87:48)
        printf "%c", x
        if(j~"^8|12|16|20")printf "-"
    }
}
```

If you want to use it more often than once every second you can call it in bash like this. Note that the awk part is changed too.

```
echo `awk 'BEGIN{for(srand('$RANDOM');j++<32;printf(j~"^9|13|17|21"?"-":E)"%c",x+(x>10?87:48))x=rand()*16}'`
```

The `echo` is added there to print a new line every time.

Answer (score 3):

## K5, 35 bytes

```
"-"/(0,8+4*!4)_32?`c$(48+!10),65+!6
```

To generate a hex alphabet I generate a character string (`` `c$ ``) from a list of digits (`48+!10`) and the first 6 capital letters (`65+!6`). An alternate way of generating the digits which is the same length is `,/$!10`.

With the string "0123456789ABCDEF" generated, the rest is simple. Select 32 random values from this set (`32?`), slice (`_`) the resulting string at `0 8 12 16 20` computed via `(0,8+4*!4)`, and then join the resulting string fragments with dashes (`"-"/`).

In action:

```
  "-"/(0,8+4*!4)_32?`c$(48+!10),65+!6
"9550E114-A8DA-9533-1B67-5E1857F355E1"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 63 bytes

```r
x=sample(c(0:9,letters[1:6]),36,1);x[0:3*5+9]='-';cat(x,sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODG3ICdVI1nDwMpSJye1pCS1qDja0MosVlPH2EzHUNO6ItrAyljLVNsy1lZdV906ObFEo0KnOLXAVl1d8/9/AA)

The code first builds a 36 character random string, and then places the four hyphens. It outputs a UUID to stdout.

Comment: Replace the `c` call with `sprintf("%x",0:15)` for -1.

Answer (score 2):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 53 bytes

The obvious one:

```perl6
say join '-',(0..9,'a'..'f').flat.roll(32).rotor(8,4,4,4,12)».join # 67
```

---

Translating the Perl 5 example using `printf`, results in code that is a bit shorter.

```perl6
printf ($_='%04x')~"$_-"x 4~$_ x 3,(0..^4⁸).roll(8) # 53
```

Comment: `(0..16⁴)`?! You can do that in Perl?

Comment: @VoteToSpam You can as of [9 days ago](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/2e8830b4f4345e4ee9c61963a7c666361efe8e54). ( Perl 6 will be released later this month )

Comment: Cooooool.  Maybe I should learn it

Comment: @VoteToSpam That's nothing compared to `1,2,4,8,16 ... *` which generates a lazy infinite list of the powers of 2. ( `{2**$++} ... *` also works )

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 175 bytes

```
fun main(a:Array<String>){
fun f()="0123456789abcdef".get((Math.random()*16).toInt())
var s=""
for(i in listOf(8,4,4,4,12)){
for(j in 1..i)
s+=f()
if(i!=12)s+="-"}
println(s)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7LDoIwFET3/Qrs6l4fjSAiGjFx6cK48AuqULwKxbTVxBi@vRYzq8mZ5Myjcw1p79VLR60kDXKzN0Z@tmdnSNc7/LIBKcCCz@NkkS6zVb6Wl2tZKS7qygEcpbsJI3XZtYDjOEPhuoN2gMje0kS24JypzgBFpKOGrDspyKfpP3GCgyHQ@0BjIQiZnRTBx0gBjYqwCJ3PeM@e4ZFrNFjsvf8B)

My first ever Kotlin program & PPCG submission

Comment: 152 bytes -> https://tio.run/##JY6xDoJAEER7vsLQsGv04iEiGDSxtDAWfsEqHF7kDnKuhSF8@4mSaV4xeTPPlhttvVdvO1OA@85pyxCuZLxONuk2y@l2LysVirpigDPxQziyZWsA5zJFwe1p7CNi8DMY0hZod3SOPsWVR1d9wL7RL74oyBbJPzJGYajrQQqheeJxegi0As1FjtOHaBnhMHj/BQ

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>115</s> 78 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429)

```apl
a←⊣,'-',⊢
H←⊃∘(⎕D,819⌶⎕A)¨16∘⊥⍣¯1
(H 8?16)a(H 4?16)a(H 4?16)a(H 4?16)a H 12?16
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBI/6pnr6P2qbYMCVCCQfdS3WUddV13nUtYjLA8xvftQxQwOoyEXHwtDyUc82INNR89AKQzOg@KOupY96Fx9ab8il4aFgYW9oppkIZJjgYCh4KBgaAVkA)

This is my first APL submission.
Huge thanks to @Adám for bearing with me at the PPCG's APL chat and for the hexadecimal conversion function.

Thanks to @Zacharý for 1 byte

Edited to fix byte count.

Comment: You can assume `⎕IO←0` at no byte cost, Adám does that alot. Also, most bytes (IIRC, all the ones you have here) can be counted as one in APL.

Comment: @Zacharý I've used TIO to count the bytes for my submission, should I have used the number of characters instead? I'm still new to PPCG and using APL, so I don't have much actual knowledge of how to do the byte count for it.

Comment: Also, you can change `a(H 12?16)` to `a H 12?16` to save one byte.

Comment: [`'-'@(+\9,3⍴5)⊢(⎕D,819⌶⎕A)[?36⍴16]`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@6rrqDhnaMpY7xo94tppqPuhZpPOqb6qJjYWj5qGcbkOmoGW1vbAaUNDSLBWn5XwAA) or [`'-'@(+\9,3⍴5)∊⌂hex?18⍴256`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L@6rrqDhnaMpY7xo94tppqPOroe9TRlpFbYG1oABYxMzUDK/hcAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 32 bytes

```
[8,4,4,4,12]m@MqG**X sG ù0X} q"-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P9pCxwQMDY1icx18C921tCIUit0VDu80iKhVKFTS/f8fAA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and welcome to Japt :) I'll take a run through your solutions so far when I can make some time (just back from holidays, so much to catch up on) but the first tip I'll offer is to familiarise yourself with the Unicode shortcuts (`m@` - `£`, for example) and, to help get you started here's a hastily golfed 24 byte version of your solution: https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=I+4wMTbsRCCjTXFHcFgpc0cg+TBYw3Et&input= Drop into the [Japt chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34018/japt) if you've any questions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>119</s> 110 bytes

```go
import(."math/rand";."fmt")
func f(){for j:=0;j<32;j++{if j>4&&j<24&&j%4<1{Print("-")}
Printf("%x",Int()%16)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BC4IwHMXv@xTjD8qGtdKkQ1r3LhFEH2DoZltsE1kkyD77Urs83nuH33udiz1v3rwT2HBlkTK9GzwDr4yA@E@EgeH@tRu4baFiII0HiuTHNlgSOkk3YH067ytdH4pKZ9mkJNaXMk11XSyalHU@3QdlPYEt0IBWLwkkI2yuc0uT/EhDiCtyuTFT0UOIltzcl1D2tGokdJ4kFIX4Aw)

- -9 by @The Thonnu

Comment: [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY5BC4IwHMXv@xTjD8qGtdKkQ1r3LhFEH2DoZltsE1kkyD77Urs83nuH33udiz1v3rwT2HBlkTK9GzwDr4yA@E@EgeH@tRu4baFiII0HiuTHNlgSOkk3YH067ytdH4pKZ9mkJNaXMk11XSyalHU@3QdlPYEt0IBWLwkkI2yuc0uT/EhDiCtyuTFT0UOIltzcl1D2tGokdJ4kFIX4Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), <strike>57,60</strike> 55 bytes

```
!n=bytes2hex(rand(UInt8,n))
join(.![4,2,2,2,6],-)|>show
```

- 57->60 a mistake
- 60->55 by @MarcMush and the broadcasting :-)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fY5BbsJADEX3PcUENokUMyKKElSp7DlAV6iLIXHI0MSGGQdaqTfphg1X4Q7cptOIVuqmsuW_sP77__OyGzprzrfrVHVoHGGtzIYHUZt3QZ-1-KYax71qRfb-UWsvpnrlI7qm49Os4l4fBvRimbwuyqwoizzXLZ9AGLZI6IwgGHCGau4h4EyNle1NB16cpS1YgrHCw1Qd5-FE9PQbHX_b4ucVySKlJAnfHVuK11GeRtnPFi_pBCbJx9KH2MsgDSxu5X-UkTGL1nmajRMA8Md-vstdvwA)

Comment: i think that it is not legal because of using the built-in `bytes2hex`...

Comment: I think that's fine, they didn't really specify what built-ins are disallowed and it's often hard to draw a line. More recent challenges don't tend to have these arbitrary limitations

Comment: `join(.![4,2,2,2,6],-)` will save some bytes

Answer (score 1):

### MATLAB/Octave , 95 bytes

```matlab
a='-';b=strcat(dec2hex(randi(16,32,1)-1)');[b(1:8) a b(9:12) a b(13:16) a b(17:20) a b(21:32)]
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl](http://perl.org), 51 bytes

```
say"xx-x-x-x-xxx"=~s/x/sprintf"%04x",rand 65536/reg
```

Requires perl5 >= 5.10 I think. For the /r modifier and for say().

Comment: Nice! That's much better than mine! Having looked at your solution, you might even be able to save more based on [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7172/9365) with `s//xx-x-x-x-xxx/;s/x/sprintf"%04x",rand 65536/eg` using `-p` flag, would also mean it works on older versions without `-E`.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion is:

echo|perl -pe's//xx-x-x-x-xxx/;s/x/sprintf"%04x",rand 65536/eg'

And thats just 48 chars between ' '. (Is this kind of cheating? Maybe not)

Comment: According to [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7172/9365) it's acceptable, I haven't had an opportunity to utilise that mechanism myself yet, but hopefully I will soon enough! Would be 49 bytes (+ `-p`) but still pretty good and I wouldn't have considered that approach without seeing your answer!

Answer (score 1):

### C++, <s>194</s> <s>193</s> <s>221</s> <s>210</s> 201 bytes

+7 bytes thanks to Zacharý ( detected a `-` that should not be at the end )

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<random>
#include<ctime>
#define L(a)for(int i=0;i<a;++i)std::cout<<"0123456789abcdef"[rand()%16];
#define P(a)printf("-");L(a)
void t(){srand(time(0));L(8)P(4)P(4)P(4)P(12)}
```

If someone has a way to get a different value every execution without changing `srand` and without including `<ctime>`, that would be great

Comment: Can't `#define L(a) for` ... be `#define L(a)for...`? (Might have already asked that)

Comment: This is invalid, there's a "-" at the end (which there shouldn't be)

Comment: @Zacharý Correction applied now

Comment: [210 bytes](https://pastebin.com/msnSC21S)

Comment: Could you do something like `"0123456789abcdef"[rand()%16]`, and then remove `f`?

Comment: You could save one byte by changing `L(a)` to `;for(...)...`, `P(a)` to `printf("-")L(a)`, then remove the semicolon before `L(8)`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if these apply to C++ as well as C, but... you can have the defines in compiler `-D...` instructions, saving you a whopping 12 bytes total. Also, instead of `rand()`, you can use `clock()` to avoid seeding *and* to get a reasonable degree of randomness, saving you 13 bytes. Furthermore, `puts()` is 2 bytes shorter than `printf()`, and using `putchar()` instead of `cout` would save you another 2. Total bytes saved: 29.

Comment: [173 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYy9DoIwFIV3n4LUmNw7NAFExFR9Agd241AL6B36k1JdDM9ei4nG4Qwn53yfco7flIpxSdpZH/Zkx@PiW7w0ndWpd/1Aps9OIHGwHsiEjA5SEOcC3SOou/TA8qJcV5t62@zkVSWCnWcecFXUFxQ/SZskzifFAIwzFLN08bTUZQHwNX6YQLqHHOexwRaqvxQlTlFLMumcADHFNw "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>42 39 37</s> 27 bytes

```
echo'-'(8+5*i.4)},hfd?36#16
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlaKNnaGCgVW1lpmhloK6u4OekpwAB@voKxampKQolGakKQX7u/1OTM/LVddU1LLRNtTL1TDRrdTLSUuyNzZQNzf7/BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 97 bytes

```
v>4448v,+<    <
0*    :  >59*0^
62v0-1_$:|>*6+^
>^>41v < @^99<
v<*2\_$:54+` |
?0>+\1-^ v*68<>
>1^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxDoMwDEDR3afw0MkpUoJMRJBlOAgyCImysdUTdw/wlzf8bf/9z2Ov1ZWZe/8GwSeBSK8DonaFokFuPTZp@QyXUg4GasrJUXCyUgRcqJ2f23FY8YIxaphTY@iUe1HQZLXe)

I'm sure this can be shrunk, but this is my first try :)

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 67 bytes

```
for l in 4 2 2 2 6;{ o+=`xxd -p -l$l</dev/random`-;}
echo ${o::-1}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), <s>143</s> <s>110</s> <s>103</s> <s>96</s> 94 bytes

Golfed down to 94 bytes thanks to ceilingcat and Jonathan Frech.

```c
(*P)()="\xf\x31À";*z=L"\10\4\4\4\14";main(n){for(;*z;*++z&amp;&amp;putchar(45))for(n=*z;n--;printf("%x",P()&amp;15));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/19DK0BTQ9NWid/wcIOStVaVrY8SBwsLC4@SdW5iZp5GnmZ1Wn6RBlDCWktbu0pNraC0JDkjsUjDxFRTEySTZwuUytPVtS4oyswrSdNQUq1Q0gnQ0FQzBCqwrv3/HwA)

Explanation:

```c
/*
  P is a pointer to a function.
  The string literal contains actual machine code of the function:

  0F 31     rdtsc
  C3        ret

  0xc3 is the first byte of the UTF-8 representation of the character À
*/
(*P)() = "\xf\61À";

// encode uuid chunk lengths as literal characters
// we use wide characters with 'L' prefix because
// sizeof(wchar_t)==sizeof(int) for 64-bit gcc C on TIO
// so z is actually a zero-terminated string of ints
*z = L"\8\4\4\4\14"

main (n)
{
    for (
        ; 

        // loop until we reach the trailing zero
        *z;

        // increase the pointer and dereference it
        *++z 
             // and output a hyphen, if the pointer does not point at zero
             && putchar(45) 
    )
        // output a random hex string with length pointed at by z
        for (n = *z; n--; printf ("%x", P()&15));
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79II0@nQrM6Lb9IwzpPV9e6oCgzryRNQ0m1QkmnQs3QVFMzsThXQ6kopaQ4WclKydZRSaNCU9O6NjcxM08Doi85I7FIq8pWiYOFhYVHyVqrylpLW7tKTa2gtAQkpWECNKRIQ6sKqOv/fwA).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thank you! Your version is very impressive!

Comment: Suggest `*z=L"\27\23\17\vz"` instead of `*z=L"\10\4\4\4\14"` and `for(n=32;n--;z+=printf("-%x"+(n!=*z),P()&15)-1)` instead of `for(;*z;*++z&&putchar(45))for(n=*z;n--;printf("%x",P()&15))`

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>94</s>   <s>91</s>  86 bytes

```c
main(i){srand(&i);i=803912;for(;i--%16||(i/=16)&&printf("-");printf("%x",rand()%16));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzurgoMS9FQy1T0zrT1sLA2NLQyDotv0jDOlNXV9XQrKZGI1Pf1tBMU02toCgzryRNQ0lXSdMaxlatUNIB69cEqtXUtK79/x8A)

I would have liked to suggest this version in a comment to Max Yekhlakov ([his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170182/81487)), but unfortunately I do not have the 50 needed reputation points yet, so here is my answer.

`803912` is `C4448` in hexadecimal, it describes how the output should be formatted (`12-4-4-4-8`), it is reversed because least significant digits will be read first.

### Edits:

- saved 3 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech
- saved 5 more bytes by replacing `srand(time(0))` with `srand(&i)`

Comment: `main(){...;int i=` can be `main(i){...;i=`.

Comment: I've been thinking something, apparently `srand()` accept an `unsigned int` as its seed parameter. On tio.run, an `unsigned int` is 4 bytes long but the UUID is 16 bytes long. This means only a tiny fraction of the valid outputs (1/2^12) will be generated, thus my solution (as well as the previous one with `time(0)`) is not valid. What do you think ?

Comment: The OP states `Assuming that your language's PRNG is perfect, all valid outputs must have the same probability of being generated.`. The seed entropy does not necessarily determine the RNG entropy, though it likely does (did not check the `srand()` implementation). However, `srand()` is to my knowledge reasonably uniform, so if the RNG was perfect, it would still be uniform. I therefore think your answer is valid.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I could also submit my answer as a function, assuming `srand()` has already been done, and in this case there will be no doubt. But I'm not sure if this is allowed, other C/C++  submissions all seem to include `srand()` int the answer (unless it does not use `rand()`)

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcvhCkAwEADgZ6Gmu7hQW6lrexdNdCuj8UPh2ad8/z9Pi/c5B15HiSB4H2mME1SCPG8JxA5GMwQrRErj84C0ViPvSeI5Q0mq01dZF0Vo/ofO9QaR35w/ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript REPL, 79 bytes

```javascript
'66-6-6-6-666'.replace(/6/g,_=>(Math.random().toString(16)+'00000').slice(2,6))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LctBDoMgEEDR4zATdbRdzE5v4MoDNBMklIYyBkivTzXxv/X/yE@KzeGoQ9LdNaupaHQU1UMzzMON2VB2RxTrYOTR9695gVXqm7KkXb@AVHWrOSQPD8bOTFcGqcRwLs@eERu2Pw)

`Math.random` may return `0`. Adding 5 zeros make the slicing get 4 `0`s

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <strike>91</strike> 89 bytes

```forth
include random.fs
hex
: f 0 4 4 4 8 20 0 do dup i = if + ." -" then 10 random 1 .r loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xDsIwFEP3nsJ0YYBWLWJAIA7AxMLIEpEf8qU0v0pSoFw@tKjyYFlPto2EZKunmS1n9g83aEJQXktXm1hY@hRHGDTY/3XArpmCFuihB@MMNtigLlGVSJY82mapo0Ud4ER6nLKlQIhEGivccbtcpwmKfp3AnhMrx9@F90F6Cm7cIgreBKtehCTzJSd0yg/KubEw@Qc)

#### Explanation

Changes the base to hexadecimal, then outputs numbers/segments of the appropriate length with dashes at specified intervals

#### Code Explanation

```forth
include random.fs          \ include the random module
hex                        \ set the base to hexadecimal
: f                        \ start a new word definition
  0 4 4 4 8                \ enter the intervals to place dashes
  20 0 do                  \ start a counted loop from 0 to 0x20 (32 in decimal)
    dup i =                \ check if we are on a character that needs a dash
    if                     \ if we are
      +                    \ calculate the next character that gets a dash
      ." -"                \ output a dash
    then                   \ end the if block
    f random               \ get a random number between 0x0 and 0xf
    1 .r                   \ output it right-aligned in 1-character space
  loop                     \ end the loop
;                          \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java with [Ten Foot Laser Pole](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Ten-Foot-Laser-Pole) v. 1.06, 126 bytes

```
String u(){return sj224.tflp.util.StringUtil.replace("aa-a-a-a-aaa","a",s->String.format("%04x",(int)(Math.random()*65536)));}
```

Tested with version 1.06 of the library, but this *should* work with any version 1.04 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 31 bytes

```python
import uuid;print(uuid.uuid4())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRKG0NDPFuqAoM69EA8TUAxEmGpqa//8DAA)

Python has an inbuilt package for this specific task. Enjoy :P

Comment: This doesn't follow the spec, since the first number of the third segment is always `4` (plus the questions says `No built-ins`)

Comment: Ahh sorry, I didn't read the question properly. I am very impatient :P. Also, could you help me understand why the 3rd segment always starts with 4? isn't uuid4 supposed to generate a random UUID?

Comment: From the comments under the question: UUID has a required format of `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` where y is one of `[89AB]`. I personally don't know why this is

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 153 bytes

```lua
math.randomseed(os.time())a=load"b=({...})[1]return('%0'..b..'x'):format(math.random(0,16^b-1))"print(table.concat({a(8),a(4),a(4),a(4),a(8)..a(4)},"-"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zY5RCsIwFATvEpC8B@3SgEgRehJReGkiFtpE0hSE0rPH@qc38GeZj2HYcZFSJskPJAkuTrP3juKMPEyemKUbozhlO1oBbHwx1@TzkgLpQ6MBC@iX5vM9pj1CXyFqKnO62dowq2caQqYsdvToY@h3cxVquRI6/k7LwAe3StWK@Y@flTc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 95 bytes

```
time {append g [format %x[expr [incr i]%4|$i<7|$i>21?"":"-"] [expr int(rand()*16)]]} 32;puts $g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaE6saAgNS9FIV0hOi2/KDexREG1Ijq1oqBIITozL7lIITNW1aRGJdPGHEjYGRnaKylZKekqxSpA1GTmlWgUJealaGhqGZppxsbWKhgbWReUlhQrqKT//w8A)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 97 bytes

```
time {append g [format %x[expr [incr i]%4||$i<7||$i>21?"":"-"] [expr int(rand()*16)]]} 32;puts $g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaE6saAgNS9FIV0hOi2/KDexREG1Ijq1oqBIITozL7lIITNW1aSmRiXTxhxE2hkZ2ispWSnpKsUqQFRl5pVoFCXmpWhoahmaacbG1ioYG1kXlJYUK6ik//8PAA)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 98 bytes

```
time {incr i;append g [format %x[expr $i%4||$i<7||$i>21?"":"-"] [expr int(rand()*16)]]} 32;puts $g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaE6My@5SCHTOrGgIDUvRSFdITotvyg3sURBtSI6taKgSEElU9WkpkYl08YcRNoZGdorKVkp6SrFKkDkM/NKNIoS81I0NLUMzTRjY2sVjI2sC0pLihVU0v//BwA)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 101 bytes

```
time {incr i;append g [format %x[expr !($i%4)&&$i>7&&$i<21?"-":""] [expr int(rand()*16)]]} 32;puts $g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaE6My@5SCHTOrGgIDUvRSFdITotvyg3sURBtSI6taKgSEFRQyVT1URTTU0l084cRNoYGdor6SpZKSnFKkCUZOaVaBQl5qVoaGoZmmnGxtYqGBtZF5SWFCuopP//DwA)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 104 bytes

```
proc D {n\ 4} {time {append g [format %x [expr int(rand()*16)]]} $n;set g}
puts [D 8]-[D]-[D]-[D]-[D 12]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcNBCoMwEAXQfU/xFxWi0IVFpOA2t4hZBJOKUMchGUEIOXu69cGT5Vcrx2OBRqYZQ0GWbQ/IjjmQxwrzPeLuBM0FEy6O2EhUdORV2/Vja23Bk6YUBGt58CkJRuNjX0bfo3/bWv8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
ØhWẋ36X€”-“µÇŒð‘¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//w5hoV@G6izM2WOKCrOKAnS3igJzCtcOHxZLDsOKAmMKm//8)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>65</s> 62 bytes

```
DEF G H?"-";:END
DEF H?HEX$(RND(65536),4);
END H G G G G H H H
```

I created a function to print 4 random hex digits: `DEF H?HEX$(RND(65536),4);:END` as well as 4 digits with a `-` after them: `DEF G:H?"-";:END`. Then it just has to call these functions a bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 109 + 5 = 114 bytes

Requires flags `-wc36`, causing +5 bytes

```
!ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
,-----.,+vv--^----^---z
?]]]--R\acd
?xx+-)\\b
?x+x-)\\c
?^xx\--\d
`-xx]v~\e
f*`)'`-\g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcYrDoAwEEVRP7tAESgPQ4LtHpBkSgrl61BlgmDrA/VccXPCfpyqWf8bVUjVlYkRGJLTbrLOOaDjMcxkRQwK5umTkaRAdhBhgGfyEHHx4YXW0he5B2@qiis07Qs)

Generates 4 random bits (the four `?`'s) and converts to hex digits:

- `0x0` - `0x9` => `0` - `9`
- `0xa` - `0xe` => `b` - `f`
- `0xf` => `a`

...a bit unconventional, but it saved me some bytes at no expense to the distribution of outcomes.

Comment: As far as I’m aware of, `-wc36` is less than 6 bytes.

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer the reason it was 6 is lost to time... perhaps I was including the space before the flags as well, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>51</s> 47 + 14 = <s>65</s> 61 bytes

Run with `ruby -rsecurerandom` (+14 bytes)

```
[8,4,4,4,12].map{|n|SecureRandom.hex n}.join ?-
```

Returns output

Answer (score 0):

## Java, <s>192</s> 181 bytes

```
interface T{static int t(){return (int)(Math.random()*65536);}static void main(String[]a){System.out.printf("aa-a-a-a-aaa".replaceAll("a","%04x"),t(),t(),t(),t(),t(),t(),t(),t());}}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Octave, <strike>106</strike> <strike>105</strike> <strike>103</strike> <strike>99</strike> 96 bytes

```
function[]=f,g=@(l)[48:57,'a':'f'](randi(16,[1 l]));strjoin({g(8),g(4),g(4),g(4),g(12)},'-'),end
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/rTQvuSQzPy861jZNJ93WQSNHM9rEwsrUXEc9Ud1KPU09VqMoMS8lU8PQTCfaUCEnVlPTurikKCs/M0@jOl3DQlMnXcMElTA00qzVUddV19RJzUv5n6ah@R8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 34 bytes

```
VS32 aYO16)s.e?}km*d4r2 6+\-bb.HMY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyzY2EghMdLf0EyzWC/VvjY7VyvFpMhIwUw7RjcpSc/DN/L/fwA)

trying to generate the indexes of where the "-" should go, and doing the replacement in a smaller way than hardcoding was an interesting challenge, and probably the hardest part.

#### Explanation

```
VS32 aYO16)                          // for N in range(32), append a random number 0-15 to the list Y
                              .HMY   // convert each number in Y to its Hex equivalent
                 m*d4r2 6            // make an array (of indexes) containing [8 12 16 20]. *4 mapped over (range(2,6) -> [2,3,4,5])
            .e                       // enumerating map on the random hex list. For each digit, index is k and value is b.
              ?}k        +\-bb       // map onto each digit the ternary question "is index k in the array of idexes?"
                                     // if no, replace with b (the value that was already there), if yes replace it with "-b".
           s                         // "".join( ) to make the list into a string
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 92 bytes

```
1 FOR I=1 TO 32:PRINT HEX$(INT(RND*16));:IF I=8 OR I=12 OR I=16 OR I=20 THEN PRINT"-";
2 NEXT
```

Generates 32 "random" hex digits, adding a hyphen in the appropriate places.

Output:

```
D36A49D6-85AC-51DC-6D84-3BB1EB1A0816
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 34 bytes

```
12N4448s$:Z15U&T)?39+;48+'.;L?45'.
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/QyM/ExMSiWMUqytA0VC1E097YUtvaxEJbXc/ax97EVF3v/38A)**

```
12                                 \ Push 12 to stack
  N                                \ Remove printing delimiter (normally a newline)
   4448s                           \ Push 4448, then split into digits
                                   \ The stack is now [12, 4, 4, 4, 8]
        $                          \ While items left on stack:
         :                         \ (top item) times do:
          Z15U                     \    Push random(0, 15)
              &T)?                 \    If bigger than 10 (a hex digit):
                  39+;             \      Add 39 (offset from ASCII numbers to lowercase)
                      48+          \   Add 48, converting it into the correct character
                         '.        \   Print and pop this character
                           ;L?45'. \ Print a dash ('-'), unless stack is now empty.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>19</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ŽΣÌε4*F15ÝΩh}J}'-ý
```

Outputs in uppercase.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9vc2FiaWX//8W9zqPDjM61NCpGMTXDnc6paH1KfSctw73//w)

**Explanation:**

```python
ŽΣÌ                  # Push compressed integer 21113
   ε          }      # Pop and map over each of its digit:
    4*               #  Multiply the current digit by 4
      F     }        #  Pop and loop that many times:
       15Ý           #   Push a list in the range [0,15]
          Ω          #   Pop and pick a random number from it
           h         #   Convert it to hexadecimal
            }J       #  After the inner loop: Join the stack together
               }'-ý '# After the map: join the list with "-"-delimiter together
                     # (after which this string is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `ŽΣÌ` is `21113`.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 79 bytes

```
a=>[8,4,4,4,12].map(g=e=>e?(16*Math.random()|0).toString(16)+g(e-1):"").join`-`
```

Comment: The function isn't running for me.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (ES6) - 102 bytes

#### UUID v4 compliant

A compaction of [broofa's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/720164) on Stackoverflow:

```
"10000000-1000-4000-8000-100000000000".replace(/[018]/g,s=>(s^Math.random()*256&15>>s/4).toString(16))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 103 bytes

```python
from random import*;print(''.join(hex(randint(2**(i*3),2**(3*i+2)))[2:]+'-'for i in [8,4,4,4,12])[:33])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCsMwDAS/4pstJS3E6qEkTzE@FNoQBSIZ4UPyercue5hh2HLVTYVaW00PZy95/8BHUau4FGOpwfv7rixh@5yhH3qLiIGRYOxCyEMEgBTnPPibX9UcOxaXnuPjvylmSDNRhta@)

Is 100% improvable...

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 120 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 15 bytes

```
8 4D₆Wk632ƈ∑ẇ\-j
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiOCA0ROKChldrNjMyxojiiJHhuodcXC1qIiwiIiwiIl0=)

### Explained

```
8 4D₆Wk632ƈ∑ẇ\-j­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
8 4D₆W            # ‎⁡Push the list [8, 4, 4, 4, 64] to the stack
      k632ƈ∑      # ‎⁢Push a string of 32 random hex digits
            ẇ     # ‎⁣Wrap into slices of lengths in the first list. The 64 is used as a value to ensure that the last 12 slice is fully captured.
             \-j  # ‎⁤And join on "-"s
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## q, 13 bytes

Not sure if it violates *"No built-ins."* hoever it's not using the built-in method to generate a random GUID which would be `rand 0Ng`. Generates 16 random bytes and packs them into a guid.

```
0x0 sv 16?0x0
```

### Example

```
q)0x0 sv 16?0x0
8e204f8d-5a0b-b188-1131-4ff06efe824d
```