# Does the string contain 2016?

Tags: string, restricted-source, code-golf

Given a string input, your task is to write a program that prints a [truthy value](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2190/20634) to STDOUT or equivalent if the input contains "2016" anywhere in it without using any built-in `contains`, `match`, `replace`, `split` or other functions that use patterns or regexes.

A truthy value also must be printed if the input contains "2016" with the *same* number of spaces between each number.

### Test Cases

```
2016
    => true
"2016"
    => true
2202012016016166
      ^^^^ => true
220201 2 0 1 6 016166
    => true
Happy New Year! It's 2016!
    => true
2016 is coming!
    => true

2_0_1_6
    => false
22001166
    => false
It's not 2015 any more
    => false
6102
    => false
201.6
    => false
20 16
    => false
2 0  1   6
    => false
```

### Rules

- Regexes and pattern matching cannot be used
- Built-in `contains`, `match`, and `replace` cannot be used
- Built-in `split` functions cannot be used (the only exception is when splitting the string into individual characters for looping through them, such as `input.split("")`)
- The code cannot contain the string "2016" in any form (unicode literals and constructing the string included - that *doesn't* mean that the characters 0, 1, 2, or 6 can't be used)
- The input may either be taken from `STDIN` or as an argument to a function
- It is safe to assume that the input will *not* contain linefeeds or newlines.
- The input may contain any printable ASCII characters (spaces included)
- A [truthy value](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2190/20634)  must be printed to `STDOUT` or equivalent if the input contains **2016**.
- A [falsey value](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2190/20634)  must be printed to `STDOUT` or equivalent if the input does *not* contain **2016**
- If using a function, instead of using `STDOUT`, the output can be the return value of the function
- The truthy/falsey value cannot be printed to `STDERR`.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/20634) apply
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins. Good luck!

### Bonus

**-30 Bytes** if the input also returns a truthy value if the spaces between the characters in 2016 are the same.

```
Happy 2 0 1 6
    => true
I can't wait for  2   0   1   6
    => true
It's almost 2 0  1   6
    => false
```

### Leaderboard

This is a Stack Snippet that generates both a leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To ensure your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline using the following Markdown template

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

Where N is the size, in bytes, of your submission

If you want to include multiple numbers in your header (for example, striking through old scores, or including flags in the byte count), just make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in your header

```
## Language Name, <s>K</s> X + 2 = N bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=67575;var OVERRIDE_USER=20634;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(-?\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: It's too vague what built ins are allowed. For example, can I split on 2016 and check if the result has multiple parts? What about a builtin that checks if a string is a prefix of another string?

Comment: So that means `a.split("")` is invalid?

Comment: I don't know what that means for my examples. I was thinking of split on a fixed string

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I updated the challange - I assumed that all languages had a function to get the individual characters of a string

Comment: Ok, then can I use `join` to intersperse a string with spaces? Slice a string at some position? Check if strings are equal? It would be nice to have a criterion for the boundary rather than checking case by case.

Comment: @xnor You can do all of those things, because they are not disallowed in the rules (`join` can only be used if it doesn't use a regex though, again, like stated in the rules)

Comment: Are we allowed to, for example, do `str(2016)` (string representation of 2016)? Technically that doesn't contain the _string_ 2016.

Comment: @Pietu1998 I included that part only to close any loopholes that may appear - but no, as it is *constructing* the string "2016"

Comment: Can I construct the string `"2 0 1 6"`?

Comment: @Mauris You found a loophole in the loophole closer... Anyways, I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to, so yes, you can construct `2 0 1 6`

Comment: This challenge has a close vote for *Unclear what you're asking*? I feel like its very clear what this challenge is asking - check if a string contains another string without directly using built-in functions that make it easy

Comment: I think they mean it's unclear what code you're asking them to produce because of the vague rules about what built-ins are allowed, no string constructing, etc...

Comment: "pattern matching cannot be used" - that rules out Haskell. I was working on a solution, but now I'm out.

Comment: "pattern matching cannot be used" - pattern matching is the entire premise of Mathematica. Expressions are matched with patterns, then evaluated.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I can't tell if you're being serious or not... You're taking it ***way*** too literally - "pattern matching can't be used" doesn't mean that the language can't be pattern matched, it means that you can't use pattern matching in your code

Comment: -1; rules are ad-hoc and arbitrary

Comment: @ThomasKwa I guess that's opinion, but I don't see how they're arbitrary - the rules all enforce that users can't just do `if(input.contains("2016")){return true;}` - I didn't just through random rules in there for no reason

Comment: The addition of many arbitrary-looking rules often means that a challenge is uninteresting or flawed.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I didn't really think that there were that many rules, but I guess if that many people agree with you, I should probably update the challenge... The "spaces" part is now a bonus, and is not required

Comment: The main problem is that the rules are not "black-and-white" for every language. I thought it was an interesting challenge (for my preferred language, JavaScript, at least) but for others that rely heavily on pattern-matching the rules become less clear. The only time that challenges with arbitrary rules (rules that prevent something which would normally not be an issue) work is when they are clear across all languages. Unfortunately the pattern matching rule here may only be clear if it is spelled out for each individual language (which is not feasible).

Comment: @user81655 Yes, the rules have a lot of grey area. I [had the same pattern matching restriction on another one of my challenges](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66496/20634), but I assume that went over well because the objective was much more clear.

Comment: Maybe the challenge would have been better received if it had a simple rule like *"No regular expressions"* like the other one had, but there are other loopholes (like the reasons you disallowed the "2016" literal and certain built-ins). Too many arbitrary rules to prevent loopholes and people won't like the challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CJam, 35 - 30 = 5 bytes

```
qS*_,,_Sf*{"2 0 1 6"\*}%\:)@few:+&`
```

### Explanation

```
qS*                                   Push s p a c e d   i n p u t.
   _,,                                Push [0..N-1] where N = len(input).
      _Sf*                            Push ["", " ", "  ", "   ", ...].
          {"2 0 1 6"\*}%              Make it ["2 0 1 6", "2   0   1   6", ...].
                        \             Swap [0..N-1] to top of stack.
                         :)           Increment each, giving [1..N].
                           @          Rotate spaced input I to top of stack.
                            few       Push [I1ew I2ew .. INew], i.e.
                               :+      when concatenated, all substrings of I.
                                 &    Intersect sets.
                                  `   Print as CJam syntax.
```

Essentially, given an input string `abcd`, this executes a "substring search" by intersecting the sets:

- `2 0 1 6`, `2   0   1   6`, ... up to `2*len(input())-1` = more than enough spaces,
- `a`, , `b`, ..., `a b`, ... `a b c d`.

If a result is found, such a spaced `2016` string appeared as a substring of the input, and a truthy list containing this result is printed, like `["2 0 1 6"]`. Otherwise, the empty list is printed.

The string `"2016"` is never constructed as the code runs; only its spaced-out versions are.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 125 - 30 = 95 bytes

```js
x=>(y=[...x]).map((_,i)=>y.map((_,j)=>r?0:(n=x.substr(j,a.length),r=n<a&n>b),s=" ".repeat(i),a=2+s+0+s+1+s,b=a+5,a+=7),r=0)|r
```

### Explanation

Returns `1` if it matched, otherwise `0`.

Brute forces every possible combination of spaces between `2016` and checks for a match at each substring. Note that it never constructs the string `2016` because it generates `a` as `2017` and `b` as `2015` (both with spaces) and checks if `b < substring < a`.

```js
x=>                             // x = input string
  (y=[...x])                    // y = input as array
  .map((_,i)=>                  // loop over every possible amount of spaces between digits
    y.map((_,j)=>               // loop over every character to check for a match
      r?0:(                     // if r is set we don't have to do anything, if not:
        n=x.substr(j,t.length), // n = substring to compare
        r=n<a&n>b               // check if r is 2016
      ),
      s=" ".repeat(i),          // s = spaces between letters
      a=2+s+0+s+1+s,            // get string to compare with
      b=a+5,                    // b = 2015 (with spaces)
      a+=7                      // a = 2017 (with spaces)
    ),
    r=0                         // r = result
  )
  |r                            // return result
```

### Test

```js
var solution = x=>(y=[...x]).map((_,i)=>y.map((_,j)=>r?0:(n=x.substr(j,a.length),r=n<a&n>b),s=" ".repeat(i),a=2+s+0+s+1+s,b=a+5,a+=7),r=0)|r
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="I can't wait for  2   0   1   6" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: It looks like this returns `false` for the input "220201 2 0 1 6 016166" - I should probably add that as a test case

Comment: @Jojodmo You're right. I changed to a brute-force approach because it was shorter than fixing my old method.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 2, <s>307</s> 297 - 30 = 267 Bytes

```
func d(s:String)->Int{var c=0;var n=0;var l=0;for v in s.characters{if(v=="2"){c=1;l=0;n=0};if(c==1&&v=="0"){c=2;l=n;n=0};if(c==2&&v=="1"){c=(l==n ?3:0);l=n;n=0};if(c==3&&v=="6"){if(l==n){return 1}else{c=0}};if(!(v=="2" || v=="0" || v=="1" || v=="6")){if(v==" "){n++}else{c=0;l=0;n=0;}}};return 0}
```

#### Ungolfed

```
func d(s: String) -> Int{
    var c=0
    var n=0
    var l=0
    for v in s.characters{
        if(v == "2"){
            c = 1
            l = 0
            n = 0
        }
        if(c == 1 && v == "0"){
            c = 2
            l = n
            n = 0
        }
        if(c == 2 && v == "1"){
            c = (l == n ? 3 : 0)
            l = n
            n = 0
        }
        if(c == 3 && v == "6"){
            if(l == n){
                return 1
            }
            else{
                c = 0
            }
        }
        //you may be wondering why I didn't use &&. It's because
        //using && would require me to use !=, which needs spaces
        //on both sides
        if(!(v == "2" || v == "0" || v == "1" || v == "6")){
            if(v == " "){
                n++
            }
            else{
                c=0
                l=0
                n=0
            }
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```