# Generate a 6 character string from a 15 character alphabet

Tags: code-golf, generation

In one of our projects at work, we recently discovered a particularly large method for generating a 6 character string from a 15 character alphabet. A few of us claimed "I bet we can get that in one line" which started a little internal game of code golf.

Your task is to beat us, which I have no doubt won't take long!

The original algorithm used the alphabet 0-9A-E, but we've experimented with other alphabets. There are therefore three subtasks.

1. Generate a `6` character string randomly selecting from an arbitrary hardcoded `15` character alphabet like `ABC123!@TPOI098`. (This is just an example, and should be customizable without affecting the byte count.)
2. Generate a `6` character string randomly selecting from a `15` character alphabet `0123456789ABCDE`.
3. Generate a `6` character string randomly selecting from a `15` character alphabet of your choice (printable characters only please).

Each character should have **equal chance** of selection and **repetition** should be possible.

The best we have been able to manage for each of the subtasks is:

- "ABC123!@TPOI098" - `24 bytes`
- "0123456789ABCDE" - `21 bytes`
- Custom alphabet   -  `13 bytes`

Your score is the sum of the bytes in each subtask's solution. i.e. our score is currently 58.

We've attempted using among others, CJam and Ruby. The original was in C#. Use any language you like, but we'll be interested to see solutions in these languages particularly

Comment: [Regarding multi-part challenges.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8463/8478) Unfortunately, I don't have a good solution in this case, since these three subtasks are way too similar for it to make sense to split them up into multiple challenges. I've also been considering proposing an exception to that policy for multi-part challenges where the subtasks are just minor variations of the same challenge. (Although that still has the problem that sub-solutions can be taken from other answers.) So I won't mod-hammer this, and see what the community thinks.

Comment: "Your score is the sum of the bytes..." so my first example is unfortunate. I'll amend to another potential example

Comment: @MartinEnder My 2 cents: I think it's OK and will not VTC. Sure, I generally think a challenge with a single interesting task is better, but since these tasks are *very* similar, it's a lot better than a "golf-course" that says "do these 8 random unrelated tasks." Even though there is no interaction between tasks, in my eyes this challenge is not very different than say [Golf all 16 logic gates](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/82938/31716).

Comment: Are there any time or memory limits? Do the subtasks have to be independent or are they allowed to share code?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Yes, that is actually the challenge which made me consider the exception I mentioned. I just didn't get around to sorting out my thoughts on the matter yet.

Comment: [Borderline dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58442/194)

Comment: Does "generate a string" mean the code has to actually generate a string value with the appropriate characters in it, or is outputting the six characters (not separated by space or newlines) acceptable?

Comment: Maybe I’m being dense here, but how can the character alphabet possibly be customisable without affecting the byte count? Wouldn’t changing the character set from `0123456789ABCDE` to `0123456789x̃ᾖत्रुँֆ齉` increase the byte count by definition (unless the encoding uses 4 bytes for all characters)? Or is ‘character’ here to be taken to refer to single-byte ASCII characters only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 38 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

TryItOnline links **A**, **B**, and **C**.

**[A](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcQUJDMTIzIUDCo1BPSTA5OOKAnVfhuos2WOKCrA&input=)**: `ABC123!@£POI098`, 22 bytes

```
“ABC123!@£POI098”Wẋ6X€
```

(thinking about a compression to lessen this one)

**[B](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5hI4bmWV-G6izZY4oKs&input=)**: `0123456789ABCDE`, 8 bytes:

```
ØHṖWẋ6X€
```

**[C](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5hI4biKV-G6izZY4oKs&input=)**:`123456789ABCDEF` (choice), 8 bytes:

```
ØHḊWẋ6X€
```

#### How?

```
...Wẋ6X€ - common theme
   W     - wrap (string) in a list
    ẋ6   - repeat six times
      X€ - random choice from €ach

ØH...... - hexadecimal digit yield: "0123456789ABCDEF"

..Ṗ..... - pop: z[:-1] (B)

..Ḋ..... - dequeue: z[1:] (C)
```

Answer (score 8):

### CJam (23 + 14 + 10 = 47 bytes)

Arbitrary alphabet: 23 bytes ([online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B%22ABC123!%40TPOI098%22mR%7D6*))

```
{"ABC123!@TPOI098"mR}6*
```

Hexadecimal alphabet: 14 bytes ([online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7BFmrAbHb'0%2B%7D6*))

```
{FmrAbHb'0+}6*
```

Custom alphabet: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO`, 10 bytes ([online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7BFmr'A%2B%7D6*))

```
{Fmr'A+}6*
```

#### Dissection

The hexadecimal one is the interesting one:

```
{      e# Loop...
  Fmr  e#   Select a random number from 0 to 14
  AbHb e#   Convert to base 10 and then to base 17
       e#   (i.e. add 7 if the number is greater than 9)
  '0+  e#   Add character '0' (i.e. add 48 and convert from integer to character)
       e#   Note that 'A' - '0' = 17
}6*    e# ...six times
```

The six characters are left on the stack and printed automatically.

Comment: `AbHb` is brilliant. I thought about that general approach but `_9>7*+` was too long.

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, 46 + 26 + 26 = 98 bytes

*A lot of the credit goes to [@Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings) for saving 13 bytes!*

The 3 programs are pretty much identical, except for the alphabet that changes.

- Hardcoded alphabet (`ABC123!@)POI098` in this example) -> 46 bytes:

  `say map{substr"ABC123!@)POI098",15*rand,1}1..6`
- Fixed alphabet `0123456789ABCDE` -> 26 bytes:

  `printf"%X",rand 15for 1..6`
- Custom alphabet `0123456789ABCDE` in that case -> 26 bytes:

  `printf"%X",rand 15for 1..6`

You can put them all in a file to run them :

```
$ cat 6chr_strings.pl
say map{substr"ABC123!@)POI098",15*rand,1}1..6;
say "";
printf"%X",rand 15for 1..6;
say "";
printf"%X",rand 15for 1..6;
say "";
$ perl -M5.010 6chr_string.pl
CB8!8!
24D582
9ED58C
```

(the `say "";` are just here to improve the output format)

Comment: Good answers! I had pretty much the same for the first and last, but you can save a byte using `say`: `say map{("ABC123!@)POI098"=~/./g)[rand 15]}1..6` and `say map{(A..O)[rand 15]}1..6`. For the second you can use `printf`: `printf"%X",rand 15for 1..6` to save 11 over all! I'm sure Ton can advise on some arcane magic to save more too!

Comment: Actually with the custom alphabet `substr` saves another: `say map{substr"ABC123!@)POI098",15*rand,1}1..6`

Comment: @DomHastings Hmm indeed, that's nice, well played! Thanks :-)

Comment: I like that you removed the note about the code being straightforward :D

Comment: @DomHastings with `printf"%X"`, `substr..rand` and `map`, it's just a bit less obvious, so I let people enjoy perl magic with no spoilers! :D

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>167</s> <s>166</s> <s>164</s> 163 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Neil*
*Saved 2 bytes thanks to ETHproductions*
*Saved 1 byte thanks to premek.v*

**Hardcoded:** `"ABC123!@TPOI098"` (58 bytes)

```
f=(n=6)=>n?"ABC123!@TPOI098"[Math.random()*15|0]+f(n-1):''
```

**Fixed:** `"0123456789ABCDE"` (<s>58</s> 57 bytes)

```
f=(n=6)=>n?f(n-1)+("ABCDE"[n=Math.random()*15|0]||n-5):''
```

**Custom:** `"()+.1=>?M[afhnt"` (<s>51</s> <s>49</s> 48 bytes)

```
f=(n=6)=>n?(f+1)[Math.random()*15|0+5]+f(n-1):''
```

Comment: `(n=6)=>n?f(n-1)+("ABCDE"[n=Math.random()*15|0]||n-5):''` saves you a byte.

Comment: `1/8+Math` is great :)

Comment: But `.1+JSON` is better ;)

Comment: Or `JSON+f` (`[object JSON](n` => `" (JNOS[]bcejnot"`)

Comment: @ETHproductions Nice one. :)

Answer (score 4):

## R, 33+43+59 = 135 bytes

Arbitrary hard-coded alphabet (change the string to change the alphabet):

```
cat(sample(strsplit("ABC123!@TPOI098","")[[1]],6,1),sep="")
```

Alphabet of `[0-9A-E]`:

```
cat(sample(c(0:9,LETTERS[1:6]),6,1),sep="")
```

User-defined alphabet from stdin:

```
cat(sample(scan(,''),6,1),sep="")
```

All cases print the output word to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 184 bytes

Custom alphabet: 66 bytes

```
_=>"......".replace(/./g,c=>"ABC123!@TPOI098"[Math.random()*15|0])
```

0-9A-E: 63 bytes

```
_=>"......".replace(/./g,c=>"ABCDE"[n=Math.random()*15|0]||n-5)
```

0-9a-e: 55 bytes

```
_=>(Math.random()*11390625+1e8|0).toString(15).slice(1)
```

(Subtract 6 bytes if date-based randomness is permissible.)

Comment: You can save a byte on the last one with `**`: `_=>((Math.random()+1)*15**6|0).toString(15).slice(1)`

Comment: @ETHproductions Surely that would make it ES7, rather than ES6? (Also, it looks like a 3-byte saving to me.)

Comment: Yes, and it does appear to save 3 bytes. I must have included the `f=` in the byte count

Answer (score 3):

## q, 42 bytes

**A**

19 bytes

```
6?"ABC123!@TPOI098"
```

**B**

14 bytes

```
6?15#.Q.n,.Q.A
```

**C**

9 bytes

```
6?15#.Q.a
```

(uses the first fifteen letters of the alphabet)

Answer (score 3):

## Julia (36+26+21 = 83)

```
join(rand(["ABC123!@TPOI098"...],6))

base(15,rand(15^6:15^7-1))

join(rand('a':'o',6))
```

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 48 bytes

Arbitrary alphabet, 23 bytes:

```
{"ABC123!@TPOI098"mR}6*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=eyJBQkMxMjMhQFRQT0kwOTgibVJ9Nio&input=)

Hex digits, 15 bytes:

```
{A,'F,65>+mR}6*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=e0EsJ0YsNjU-K21SfTYq&input=)

Alphabet `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO`, 10 bytes:

```
{Fmr'A+}6*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=e0ZtcidBK302Kg&input=)

Comment: I had a bad idea. If we consider U+FFFE a character, `~c` instead of `'A+` returns something technically printable.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. I didn't find a definition of printable Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby 47 + 37 + 31 = 115**

Hardcoded: "ABC123!@TPOI098" (47)

```
(1..6).map{"5CABC123!@TPOI098".chars.sample}*''
```

Fixed: "0123456789ABCDE" (37)

```
(1..6).map{[*0..9,*?A..?E].sample}*''
```

Custom: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO" (31)

```
(1..6).map{[*?A..?O].sample}*''
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 43 bytes

Arbitratry alphabet (`ABC123!@TPOI098`), 23 bytes [Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IkFCQzEyMyFAVFBPSTA5OCI2Ri5ywqw_&input=)

```
"ABC123!@TPOI098"6F.r¬?
```

Almost hexadecimal alphabet (`0123456789ABCDE`), 10 bytes [Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MTTDnWg2Ri5ywqw_&input=)

```
14Ýh6F.r¬?
```

Custom alphabet (`abcdefghijklmno`), 10 bytes [Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=QTE1wqM2Ri5ywqw_&input=)

```
A15£6F.r¬?
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 70 + 70 + 64 = 204 bytes

```python
from random import*
s=""
exec"s+=choice('ABC123!@TPOI098');"*6
print s

from random import*
s=""
exec"s+=choice('0123456789ABCDE');"*6
print s

from random import*
s=""
exec"s+=chr(randint(65,80));"*6
print s
```

Unfortunately, the second example is easier with the first method than something like `choice([randint(48,57)),choice(65,69)])`

Comment: Why do you use `from random import*`? I think you can use `import random` and `random.choice` at least in the first two examples.

Comment: `import random random.choice` is 27 but `from random import* choice` is 26, also `import random as r r.choice` is 27

Comment: For the hex case, we can do a bit better by using `format(randrange(8**8),'X')`, I think.

Comment: @DSM the problem is, there must be no `F`

Answer (score 1):

## Vitsy, 27 + <s>24</s> 22 + <s>13</s> 10 = <s>64</s> <s>62</s> 59 bytes

#1:

```
"ABC123!@TPOI098"6\[eR2+@O]
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=IkFCQzEyMyFAVFBPSTA5OCI2XFtlUjIrQE9d&input=)

#2:

```
aH7+D4+H6\[eR2+@68*+O]
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=YUg3K0Q0K0g2XFtlUjIrQDY4KitPXQ&input=)

#3:

```
6\[eR5F-O]
```

Where the available characters are:

```
ﾖﾕﾔﾓﾒﾑﾐﾏﾎﾍﾌﾋﾊﾉﾈ
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=NlxbZVI1Ri1PXQ&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 24 + 24 + <s>18</s> 10 = 58 bytes

*8 bytes saved thanks to miles!*

```
'ABC123!@TPOI098'{~?6#15
'0123456789ABCDE'{~?6#15
u:65+?6#15
```

Yeah, the second string isn't easily compressible in J:

```
u:47+23#.inv 12670682677028904639x
u:47+;(+i.@])/"1&.>1 10;18 5
('ABCDE',~1":i.10)
(toupper,hfd?6#15)
'0123456789ABCDE'
```

If a lowercase hex alphabet is fine, then there's `,hfd?6#15` for 9 bytes, as @miles noted.

Anyhow, `?6#15` is 6 random numbers between 0 and 15; `{~` is take-from. `u:` converts numbers to chars. The last example encodes `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP`.

### Bonus: general case

```
{~6?@##
```

`{~6?@##` is roughly:

```
{~6?@##  input: y
      #  length of y
  6  #   six copies of the length
   ?@    random numbers between 0 and the length
{~       taken from y
```

Comment: On the second case, there's a builtin named `hfd` which converts to **h**ex **f**rom **d**ecimal. You can get a 9 byte solution using `,hfd?6#15`. The last case, just to have something easily read, uses the alphabet from `'A'` for a 10 byte solution `u:65+?6#15`, making a total 24 + 9 + 10 = 45.

Comment: @miles I think the second case requires capitalized letters. As for the last case... haha, oops. I completely forgot about vectorized addition.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 46+36+35=117 bytes

#### Hardcoded (46 bytes)

```
for(;$i++<6;)echo"ABC123!@TPOI098"[rand()%15];
```

<s>(47 bytes)</s>

```
for(;$i++<6;)echo"ABC123!@TPOI098"[rand(0,14)];
```

#### Hexadecimal (lowercase) (36 bytes)

```
for(;$j++<6;)echo dechex(rand()%15);
```

For uppercase, 46 bytes with Hardcoded version.

#### Custom (A-O) (35 bytes)

```
for(;$k++<6;)echo chr(rand(65,79));
```

Comment: I don't think I can accept your 2nd part. a-e isn't the same as A-E

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 154 bytes

Hardcoded alphabet (54 bytes):

```
Seq.fill(6)("ABC123!@TPOI098"((math.random*14).toInt))
```

Hex alphabet (54 bytes):

```
Seq.fill(6)("0123456789ABCDE"((math.random*14).toInt))
```

Custom alphabet `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO` (47 bytes):

```
Seq.fill(6)(('A'to'O')((math.random*14).toInt))
```

Explanation:

```
Seq.fill(6)(               //build a sequence of 6 elements, where each element is...
  "ABC123!@TPOI098"(         //from the string
    (math.random*14).toInt   //take a random char
  )
)
```

`'A'to'O'` creates a sequence of 15 chars, A to O

Answer (score 0):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 42 bytes

Hardcoded alphabet, 22 bytes:

```
L6ORC"ABC123!@TPOI098"
```

Hex digits, 11 bytes:

```
L6ORR15TB16
```

First 15 lowercase letters, 9 bytes:

```
L6Oz@RR15
```

#### Explanation

All three programs start with `L6O`: loop 6 times and output the given expression.

- `RC"..."`: Random Choice of a character from the hard-coded string
- `RR15TB16`: RandRange(15), converted To Base 16
- `z@RR15`: lowercase alphabet `z`, indexed with RandRange(15)

[Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=TDZPUkMiQUJDMTIzIUBUUE9JMDk4IiAgaGFyZGNvZGVkIGFscGhhYmV0ClB4ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHByaW50IGEgbmV3bGluZQpMNk9SUjE1VEIxNiAgICAgICAgICAgICBoZXggZGlnaXRzClB4ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHByaW50IGEgbmV3bGluZQpMNk96QFJSMTUgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBsb3dlcmNhc2UgbGV0dGVycw&input=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Skript](http://skunity.com)/[skQuery](http://skunity.com/SkQuery), 108 bytes

Hardcoded (43 bytes):

```
random 6 char string from `A@cD%F3h9JK{mN!`
```

0123456789ABCDE (34 bytes):

```
random 6 char string from `0-9A-E`
```

Choice (31 bytes):

```
random 6 char string from `A-M`
```

Comment: Can you move the opening `\`` to the left?

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE No, it doesn't let you

Answer (score 0):

## Jolf, 26 + 14 + 13 = 51 bytes

```
Μ*S6d rG"ABC123!@TPOI098"E
```

Custom alphabet, 24 bytes. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=zpwqUzZkIHJHIkFCQzEyMyFAVFBPSTA5OCJF)

```
Μ*S6d r lp^0wά
```

0-9A-E alphabet, 14 bytes. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=zpwqUzZkIHIgbHBeMHfOrA) `lp^0wά` is `lp` (0-Z) sliced (`l`) from `0` to `15` (`wά`).

```
Μ*S6d r lp^1ά
```

1-9A-F alphabet, 13 bytes. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=zpwqUzZkIHIgbHBeMc6s) `lp^1ά` is the same as above, except from `1` to `16`.

---

General method:

```
Μ*S6d r
M*S6d      map six newlines over this function:
      r    select random element from array.
```

Other attempts (using string compression):

```
Μ*S6d rGμpwΞ $AE
```

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 45 + 44 + 37 = 126 bytes

Fixed alphabet, 45 bytes

```
-join(0..5|%{'ABC123!@TPOI098'[(Random)%15]})
```

Nearly-hexadecimal alphabet, 44 bytes

```
-join[char[]](0..5|%{Random(48..57+65..69)})
```

Custom alphabet (A to O), 37 bytes

```
-join[char[]](0..5|%{Random(65..79)})
```

All of these follow the same pattern -- loop from `0` to `5`, each iteration selecting a `Random` character or ASCII value, casting that as a `char`-array if necessary, and `-join`ing it together into a string. That string is left on the pipeline, and output is implicit.

---

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> -join(0..5|%{'ABC123!@TPOI098'[(Random)%15]})
32ATB3

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> -join(0..5|%{'ABC123!@TPOI098'[(Random)%15]})
III@B2

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> -join(0..5|%{'ABC123!@TPOI098'[(Random)%15]})
@302O@

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> -join[char[]](0..5|%{Random(48..57+65..69)})
74E117

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> -join[char[]](0..5|%{Random(48..57+65..69)})
09D7DD

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> -join[char[]](0..5|%{Random(65..79)})
COJDFI

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> -join[char[]](0..5|%{Random(65..79)})
EAKCNJ
```

Answer (score -1):

### Pyke, 35 bytes

#### Arbitary alphabet, 20 bytes

```
6V"ABC123!@TPOI098"H
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=6V%22ABC123%21%40TPOI098%22H)

#### Hex alphabet, 8 bytes

```
6V~J15<H
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=6V~J15%3CH)

```
~J15< - "0123456789abcdefghijklmno..."[:15]
```

#### Custom alphabet, 7 bytes

```
6VG15<H
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=6VG15%3CH)

```
G15< - alphabet[:15]
```

Alphabet chosen: `abcdefghijklmno`

```
6V     - repeat 6 times:
  ...  -   get alphabet
     H -  choose_random(^)
```

Comment: This seems to output 6 chars separated by newline instead of a 6-char string.

Comment: The question doesn't state the output format.

Comment: I see the words *Generate a 6 character string* in 4 places in the specification.